# Помогите правильно связать таблицы и организовать их работу

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, jpa

Нужно правильно организовать связь One-to-Many.

Есть Таблица Client

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "client", catalog = "bank")
public class Client implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5527566248002296042L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "client")
    private Set<Credit> credits;
```

и есть таблица Кредитных линий (потом из этих данных будут делаться расчеты)

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "credit", catalog = "bank")
public class Credit implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5924361831551833717L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "credit_id")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "sum")
    private long sum;
    @Column(name = "month")
    private long month;
    @Column(name = "percent")
    private double percent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false)
    private Client client;
```

Есть JSP страницы которые отдельно отображает только Клиентов и Кредиты в которой организованы CRUD операции над таблицами.

```
<h1>Client List</h1>

<c:if test="${!empty listClients}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">ID</th>
            <th width="120">Name</th>
            <th width="120">Surname</th>
            <th width="120">Address</th>
            <th width="120">Phone</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>
            <th width="120">View Credit Line</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listClients}" var="client">
            <tr>
                <td>${client.id}</td>
                <td>${client.name}</td>
                <td>${client.surname}</td>
                <td>${client.address}</td>
                <td>${client.phone}</td>
                <td>${client.credits}</td>
                <%--<td>${client.credits}</td>--%>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${client.id}'/>">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${client.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value="/credits"/>" target="_blank">Credit line</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
```

```
<h1>Credit Line Clients</h1>

<c:if test="${!empty listCredits}">
    <table class="tg">
        <tr>
            <th width="80">ID</th>
            <th width="120">Sum</th>
            <th width="120">Month</th>
            <th width="120">Percent</th>
            <th width="60">Edit</th>
            <th width="60">Delete</th>

        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listCredits}" var="credit">
            <tr>
                <td>${credit.id}</td>
                <td>${credit.sum}</td>
                <td>${credit.month}</td>
                <td>${credit.percent}</td>

                <td><a href="<c:url value='/editCredits/${credit.id}'/>">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="<c:url value='/removeCredits/${credit.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

---

```
@Repository
public class CreditDaoImpl implements CreditDao {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CreditDaoImpl.class);


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }


    @Override
    public void addCredit(Credit credit) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(credit);
        logger.info("креди оформлен" + credit);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateCredit(Credit credit) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(credit);
        logger.info("кредит обвнолен" + credit);

    }

    @Override
    public void removeCredit(long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Credit credit = (Credit) session.load(Credit.class, new Long(id));
        if (credit != null) session.delete(credit);
        logger.info("credit this delete " + credit);

    }

    @Override
    public Credit getCreditById(long id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Credit credit = (Credit) session.load(Credit.class, new Long(id));
        logger.info("кредит загружен " + credit);
        return credit;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Credit> listCredits() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<Credit> creditList = session.createQuery("from Credit ").list();
        for (Credit credit : creditList) logger.info("client list" + credit);
        return creditList;
    }
```

### }

```
@Repository
public class ClientDaoImpl implements ClientDao {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClientDaoImpl.class);


@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
public void addClient(Client client) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(client);
    logger.info("клиент добавлен " + client);
}

@Override
public void updateClient(Client client) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.update(client);
    logger.info("клиент обновлен " + client);

}

@Override
public void removeClient(long id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Client client = (Client) session.load(Client.class, new Long(id));
    if (client != null) session.delete(client);
    logger.info("клиент удален " + client);

}

@Override
public Client getClientById(long id) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Client client = (Client) session.load(Client.class, new Long(id));
    logger.info("Client successfully loaded. Client details:" + client);
    return client;
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Client> listClients() {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    List<Client> clientList = session.createQuery("from Client").list();
    for (Client client : clientList) logger.info("client list" + client);
    return clientList;
}
```

}

Мне нужно что бы когда я создаю клиента и у него создаю кредитные линии они принадлежали только ему.
И когда я захожу на разных клиентов кредиты хранились только конкретного клиента.

Comment: в чем сообственно проблема? у вас готово это

Comment: Когда я добавляю в кредиты новые данные вылетает.

HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.bankapp.model.Credit.client


Но когда я убираю nullable = false то сохранение идет ( но не к каждому клиенту конкретно его кредитные линии).
@BogdanK

Comment: такая ошибка возникает при сохранение связок, попробуйте сначала сохранить `Client`, после этого обект класса `Client` вставте в `Credit` и сохранить.
Или добавьте еще код _репозитория_ чтобы посмотреть, JSP здесь явно лишнее

Comment: Я так и делаю как вы сказали.

Код добавил.@BogdanK

Comment: странно, а если использовать `save` вместо `persist` ???

Comment: Только что изменил, летит тоже самое.

Залил на GitHub если не тяжело гляньте. https://github.com/VMAproject/BankApplication

Сил нету уже и пример найти не могу.

Comment: ок, сейчас гляну

Comment: `CreditController.addCredit` -> `else this.creditService.updateCredit(credit);`
здесь значение для `clien = null`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52128/discussion-between-verlamov-and-bogdank).